# Xamarin forms: UWP app breaks when the code execution comes to displayalert line

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, alert

I am using `displayalert` in my project and it is working fine on `android` and `ios` devices. But for the `UWP` part it is not working in some pages. When the code execution comes to `displayalert` line the `UWP` app breaks and redirecting to `App.g.i.cs`. Code control comes to the following if block.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

If I mouse over the `e` showing `{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}`

I am using the following code for display alert:

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert", "A verification code has been sent to your email.", "OK");
```

If I changed the above lines like below, no issue will come.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
{
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "A verification code has been sent to your email.", "OK");
});
```

Is there any solution for this issue without adding `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`? And what is the reason behind this issue?

**Sample code**: Following code is a button clicked code. When the code execution comes to any of the display alert line, getting the above error.

```
async void ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Signing in...");
            var name = usernameEntry.Text;
            var password = passwordEntry.Text;

            if (Utility.IsInternet())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                {
                    UserLogin(name, password);
                }
                else
                {
                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please enter all details", "Ok");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No internet connection", "Ok");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where this line is:

`await DisplayAlert("Alert", "A verification code has been sent to your email.", "OK");`

You can do it without `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. But I think it is important to know what `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` does first.

Whenever you execute something on a different thread than the main thread, it will run in the background. The main thread is the only thread that can interact with the UI, simply because else it will become a mess with race conditions and unpredictable UI behavior. This is, as far as I know, true for every programming language.

That means, that whatever code is surrounding your alert is running in a background thread. That is why you are getting this exception. To execute something on the main thread (and thus have access to the UI), you can wrap it in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` call.

Since we don't know what the rest of your code looks like, it is hard to tell if you can show an alert without wrapping is in the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` call. But hopefully, with this information, you can figure that out yourself.

Comment: he uses [this lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) and there is a [question related](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/197) to this.

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t see how this relates

Comment: added a sample code in the question, can you please check. Which is a button onclick code.

Comment: @magicandre1981 and Gerald What is a main thread? Is button clicked function is a main thread part?